# How to change ListBox DataTemplate in WPF based on CheckBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate, datatrigger

I am trying to apply a `DataTrigger` to change the `DataTemplate` for a `ListBox` and am getting the error:

`"Error 1   Cannot find the Trigger target 'IssueListBox'.  (The target must appear before any Setters, Triggers, or Conditions that use it.)"`

I have a `ListBox` in my main `Window` (In a `DockPanel` along with other controls):

```
<ListBox x:Name="IssueListBox"
  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShowIssueSimple}" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    BorderThickness="3" DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2"/>
```

I have a pair of `DataTemplate`s in App.xaml with a `DataTrigger` at the bottom of the 2nd template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ShowIssueDetail">
        <Border CornerRadius="4, 8, 4, 8" Margin="2" MinWidth="400" BorderThickness="3" 
                BorderBrush="{Binding Path=IssUrgency, Converter={StaticResource IntToRYGBBoarderBrushConverter}}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <StackPanel Margin="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssSubject}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
                    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Due: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssDueDate}" FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Category: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssCategory}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ShowIssueSimple">

        <Border CornerRadius="6" 
                Margin="2,1,2,1"
                MinWidth="400"
                BorderThickness="2" 
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                BorderBrush="{Binding Path=IssUrgency, Converter={StaticResource IntToRYGBBoarderBrushConverter}}">
            <StackPanel Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssSubject}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource sbvm}, Path=ShowDetailListItems}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="IssueListBox" Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ShowIssueDetail}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

How do I get the `Trigger` to work? Mr Google has failed me, many examples like this abound but they are not based on another control.

Comment: In the DataTrigger, you are setting the ItemTemplate to the DataTemplate that contains it - ShowIssueSimple. Is this just a typo? I'm guessing you meant Value="{StaticResource ShowIssueDetail}".

Comment: Yes, YES a "Typo" ( :

Thanks for the heads up, fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data template is a StaticResource defined in app.xaml, you are trying to do an element name binding to the element IssueListBox which doesnt exist in the same scope. Even then what you are trying to do is this. Listbox has a data template DT, inside DT you are trying to reach back to the List box and set its DataTemplate to another one (not DT).

Why dont you combine the templates, set the visibility on the details to collapsed and trigger the visibility based on your property. then you dont have to reference the list box at all and the template stays the same, it just changes internally when you want to see the details.

Comment: That did the trick although I am still left wondering how I would handle it if I needed two templates. Life was so much easier when I just added an event handler to the checked.changed event but I am trying to develop better habits as I am learning adn make things as MVVMish as I can while learnign xaml.

Comment: you can use a data template selector, but that is to decide between data templates when they are added, not when properties change.